# Where should I continue after the third anime season?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

I plan to read manga of *The World God Only Knows*.

I've watched up to and including season 3 of the anime. Which chapters do I need to start at to continue?

Comment: @LoganM It would be best if you updated your answer to the other question to indicate where season 3 actually ended (and/or confirm that it indeed ended at chapter 190 like you guessed) before closing this one as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @senshin I did confirm in the comments there that it ended at chapter 189, but you're right that it should be in the main post. I've updated my answer there; it now covers everything in the anime to date.

Answer (score 0):

According to [BakaUpdates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=27467):

> Anime Start/End Chapter
>  Starts at Vol 1, Chap 1
>  Ends at
> Vol 19, Chap 189

So you should read from chapter 189 onward if you don't want to read what has also been aired.
Though personally I always advice to read the full manga too, so that you don't miss out on interactions that did not appear in the Anime etc.